# Let $x,y \ge 0 $.Find the maximum value of $\cfrac{(3x+4y)^2}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: inequality

Let $x,y \ge 0 $.Find the maximum value of $\cfrac{(3x+4y)^2}{x^2+y^2}$

This exercise is from the chapter of my book regarding the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality but I don't know if I've applied it correctly .

The problem asks for the maximum value of the expression so it's clear that it must be on the lesser side of the Cauchy Inequality ,i.e. 
\begin{array}
 RR&\ge \cfrac{(3x+4y)^2}{x^2+y^2} \\
R(x^2+y^2) &\ge (3x+4y)^2 \\
\left(\left(\sqrt{R}\right)^2 \right)  (x^2+y^2) &\ge (3x+4y)^2 \\
\end{array}
Now this would be true iff 
$$ \left(\left(\sqrt{R}\right)^2 +(4)^2\right)  (x^2+y^2) \ge (3x+4y)^2 $$ where $R=9$ ,which would imply that this is the maximum.

However I am not really sure if I am correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right till 
$$R (x^2+y^2) \ge (3x+4y)^2$$

Now comparing with the CS inequality
$$(3^2+4^2)(x^2+y^2) \ge (3x+4y)^2$$
$\implies R = 3^2+4^2 = 25$.

Comment: My bad you're right ,I was so focused on that $R$.Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 1):

I think ,you can consider as taking $x=\frac{4y}{3}$; 
 $\left(\left(\sqrt{R}\right)^2 +(\frac{4}{3})^2\right)  (x^2+y^2) \ge (3x+4y)^2$
which R=25 for maximum value.

Comment: why do you let $\cfrac{4}{3}$ instead of $4$ ?

Comment: Actually @Macavity approached to the answer in a better way , if u wanna follow ur way, similar approach taking x=4y/3 will solve the question.